# Can the delayed_job gem be used outside of Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

Is it possible to use the delayed_job gem outside of Rails? Or put another way, can it be used in a pure Ruby project?

If so, how?

Comment: I use the beanstalker daemon with the stalker gem.  http://railscasts.com/episodes/243-beanstalkd-and-stalker  Read through the comments for the pros and cons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why this person never posted this.

It's easy.  Two steps:

http://brkrd.com/post/45269754283/delayed-job-without-rails

**UPDATE** Looks like the link is broken.

You will need Active Record, but not Rails.  You will have to mock a Rails object, and load your database information, environment, and root into the Rails object so that DelayedJob thinks it's in the Rails environment.

Comment: Thank you for this :) delayed_job works great in just a ruby app w/ `active_record`.  Using in Sinatra was so simple :)

Answer (score 3):

Delayed Job looks heavily rails dependent.  https://github.com/defunkt/resque  resque is a very good gem that is not rails dependent that accomplishes the same goal.  You do however have to have redis on your machine which is very lightweight.  Resque also has a cool Sinatra web console to see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... I already reviewed resque and read (https://github.com/blog/542-introducing-resque) ... and decided to use delayed_job instead. It is enough for my project. But if I can not use delayed_job in this (ruby) project ... I'll go with resque.

Comment: Yeah delayed job uses a migration just to set it up.  I guess you could technically make the table in mysql and set any environment variables it needs, but I find when you take rails integrated things off rails it is a big headache.  Resque is pretty good, and is not coupled to rails at all.

Comment: You don't have to have redis on your machine. You can use the hosted service Redis To Go. There is even a 5MB free plan, so you can try it out at no cost.